# Trouble with Visual Studio 2015 and Xamarin (Android Development)

Tags: android, xamarin

I need some help with the designer of the visual studio/xamarin on the android.

I'm kinda noob with development, but I was hoping to do some examples, but the designer isn't showing up...

The tutorial videos, from the Xamarin itself, only says it need to create a new project and play with the designer, but when I do that, the designer is empty and I can't do nothing...

Here some pictures from what I have and from what I see on videos:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple things I'm thinking here. It's quite possible that your installation of Xamarin didn't go according to plan. Check your detailed Visual Studio version information in "Help -> About -> Copy Detailed Info".

Additionally, you might also be running on an outdated version of the Android SDK or there might be an issue with your Java config. Ensure you've got the Android SDK installed and updated and that you're using a current version of the Java SDK.

I also see there's a white box showing up on your Designer screen. Does that ever populate with an error? Usually, that will show some info on what exactly is going wrong.

Lastly, you can also check your logs in the following directory for more hints as to what's going on:

`%LOCALAPPDATA%\Xamarin\Log`

I hope this helps!

Comment: I was having indeed trouble with the version of the SDK... But it showed the message in the white box saying that it was out of date... But I updated with android sdk manager and the message was gone.... I will see the log to get more info

Comment: Thanks for your help.. I get an error in the log, but an update just came out and now it's working... \o/